# Extracting audio from mimeType "video/webm" into "audio/wav" for Speech-to-Text

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, mediarecorder, google-cloud-speech

I am using a MediaRecorder with mimeType "video/webm" but would like to upload only the audio of that video with type "audio/wav" to the Google Speech-to-Text service. My current code below returns a file with type "video/x-matroska". How can I solve this problem so that "audio/wav" is used?
I would like to mention that I need the video as well for a separate service so I can't just record only audio initially.

```
const handleStartCaptureClick = useCallback(() => {
      console.log('handleStartCaptureClick')
      setCapturing(true);
      mediaRecorderRef.current = new MediaRecorder(webcamRef.current.stream, {
        mimeType: "video/webm"
      });

      mediaRecorderRef.current.addEventListener(
        "dataavailable",
        handleDataAvailable
      );
      
      mediaRecorderRef.current.start();
    }, [webcamRef, setCapturing, mediaRecorderRef]);
```

```
const handleDownload = useCallback(() => {
      if (recordedChunks.length) {
        const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
          type: "audio/wav"
        });
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.style = "display: none";
        a.href = url;
        a.download = "react-webcam-stream-capture.wav";
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        setRecordedChunks([]);
      }
    }, [recordedChunks]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use library like ffmpeg to convert your video/webm to audio/wav.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32631636)